# ApplicationBarIconButton Click Event Crash

Tags: windows-phone-7, click

I'm not sure what's wrong/what I'm missing but I get the following error:

"AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE"

Whenever I add a "Click=" to my xaml for the application bar.

I have this code currently:

`<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar.Settings.png"    Text="Settings" Click="Settings_Click"/>`

The method Settings_Click exists, beyond that, I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the method has the right signature?

```
void Settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: Yup. Maybe I'll try remaking the page.

Answer (score 2):

My Advice: If you always give your buttons a name and let visual studio intellisence to create handler methods this never happens:

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="btnSettings" IconUri="..." Text="Settings" 
         Click="[let intellisence complete this]"/>
```